# Podio Php - limit the amount of item fields returned

Tags: php, podio

Is there any way that you can limit the fields that are retured when you filter for items in an app. Instead of returning all fields, I would like to return just the item-id and the title field

Comment: Can you add some code examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I will have to post actual code later when I fire up my laptop. I'm using this as an example.  But it returns the the whole item. I would like to choose which fields are returned.https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fields parameter for that.
More details on how it works and how else it could be used are right here: https://developers.podio.com/index/api in "Bundling responses using fields parameter" section.

Using fields to bundle objects can be a way to drastically reduce the amount of API requests you have to make.

Most likely you are looking for `fields=items.view(micro)` parameter. Podio API will return then only 5 values for each item:
`app_item_id`, `item_id`, `title`, `link`, `revision`

**PHP** sample

```
$items = PodioItem::filter($appCreds->app_id, 
                           array('limit' => $maxItems, 
                                 'offset' => $offset, 
                                 'filters' => $filters ), 
                           array('fields' => 'items.view(micro)'));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!
Implementaion:
$actionExists = PodioItem::filter($appCreds->app_id, array(
                'limit' => $maxItems,
                'offset' => $offset,
                'filters' => $filters
            ), array('fields' => 'items.view(micro)',
            ));

Comment: thanks for confirming, I've included your sample in answer for better visibility

Comment: Is there any way to return a specific subset of fields (in order to lighten up the work load), instead of just the default `mini`/`micro`/`full` views?