# Podio View returns too many fields

Tags: podio

I'm using the API call [Items: Filter items by view](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-by-view-4540284)

`POST /item/app/{app_id}/filter/{view_id}/`

The issue I'm having is that Podio is returning many fields specifically excluded from the view.

The app has many calculation fields which contain a lot of data.

I've defined a view to only return the fields I'm interested in, and in the UI in table view, it shows correctly (only 2 fields are included in the view).

But when fetching the view data via API, I get all the calculation fields in the app items that I'm not interested in.

Is this a bug or "expected" behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You can only partially control list of fields returned by filter-items-by-view call.

Please review similar question answered here: [Podio Php - limit the amount of item fields returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909025/podio-php-limit-the-amount-of-item-fields-returned)