# Podio filter items from app and return only some fields

Tags: podio

How do I retrieve only some fields of the filtered items? I have tried this:

```
$filtered_values=PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes,array('external_id' => array('last-name')));
```

But it also returns the other fields (not only the last-name field of the filtered items).

fields=items.view(micro) is not an answer for me. Podio API will return then only 5 values for each item: app_item_id, item_id, title, link, revision . I need other fields .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002755/podio-view-returns-too-many-fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Podio Php - limit the amount of item fields returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909025/podio-php-limit-the-amount-of-item-fields-returned)

Answer (score 0):

While making a podio Get or Filter item call, Podio will only provide fields with values for each item. Fields that are not having values will not be given.